# Paradigms for changing data types in a large java project

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have a fairly large scale java project that is in the process of being updated to integrate with a new service. The old service uses Id columns in the form of Long and the new Service uses String. So im facing the challenge of converting the data types of the affected columns which is quite wide spread given that there are sql queries, packages, DTO, and DAO objects all that reference these fields as they currently exist as a Long datatype.

Are there any good processes or design pattern to follow in this kind of situation.

Comment: Is your new system using String datatype to store long or is a new String (Alphanumaric) ID?

Comment: New System is storing Alphanumeric ids length 18